# How to build DataFrame row-by-row with correct dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a DataFrame that I build row-by-row (by necessity). My issue is that at the end, all `dtypes` are `object`. This is not so if the DataFrame is created with all the data at once.

Let me explain what I mean.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

# Example data
cols = ['P/N','Date','x','y','z']
PN = ['10a1','10a2','10a3']
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2022-07-01','2022-07-03','2022-07-05'])
xd = [0,1,2]
yd = [1.1,1.2,1.3]
zd = [-0.8,0.,0.8]
# Canonical way to build DataFrame (if you have all the data ready)
dg = pd.DataFrame({'P/N':PN,'Date':dates,'x':xd,'y':yd,'z':zd})
display(dg)
dg.dtypes
```

Here's what I get. Note the correct `dtypes`:

[image: Results]

OK, now I do the same thing row-by-row:

```
# Build empty DataFrame
cols = ['P/N','Date','x','y','z']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
# Add rows in loop
for i in range(3):
    new_row = {'P/N':PN[i],'Date':pd.to_datetime(dates[i]),'x':xd[i],'y':yd[i],'z':zd[i]}
    # deprecated
    #df = df.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([new_row])],ignore_index=True)
display(df)
df.dtypes
```

Note the `[]` around `new_row`, otherwise you get a stupid error. (I really don't understand the deprecation of `append`, BTW. It allows for much more readable code)

But now I get this: This isn't the same as above, all the `dtypes` are `object`!

[image: Results2]

The only way I found to recover my dtypes is to use `infer_objects`:

```
# Recover dtypes by using infer_objects()
dh = df.infer_objects()
dh.dtypes
```

And `dh` is now the same as `dg`.
Note that even if I do

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([new_row]).infer_objects()],ignore_index=True)
```

above, it still does not work. I believe this is due to a bug in `concat`: when an empty DataFrame is concat'ed to a non-empty DataFrame, the resulting DataFrame fails to take over the dtypes of second DataFrame. We can verify this with:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(),df],ignore_index=True).dtypes
```

and all `dtypes` are still `object`.
Is there a better way to build a DataFrame row-by-row and have the correct dtypes inferred automatically?

Comment: 1- if I run your loop I get the correct dtypes. 2- don't generate a DataFrame by adding rows in a loop, this is a quadratic behavior. 3- collect the data in lists/dictionaries and convert to DataFrame **once** in the end.

Comment: A bit explanation on @mozway's comment: append to a list is `O(1)`, append to a dataframe `df` is `O(len(df))` because you'll be copying the data. This is not to mention unexpected behavior as you are experiencing in this question.

Comment: @mozway, re: your #1: I am on Python 3.9 and pandas 1.4.2. I understand that building a DataFrame row-by-row is inefficient. In this case, it doesn't matter as my dataframe is not large and doing so significantly simplifies the code. It is not the point of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)` columns are all of type `object` because it has no data to infer dtypes from. So you need to set them with `astype`. Like @mozway commented it is recommended to use a list to add the from the loop.
I expect this to work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['P/N','Date','x','y','z']
dtypes = ['object', 'datetime64[ns]', 'int64', 'float64', 'float64']
PN = ['10a1','10a2','10a3']
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2022-07-01','2022-07-03','2022-07-05'])
xd = [0,1,2]
yd = [1.1,1.2,1.3]
zd = [-0.8,0.,0.8]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols).astype({c:d for c,d in zip(cols,dtypes)})
new_rows = []
for i in range(3):
    new_row = [PN[i], pd.to_datetime(dates[i]), xd[i], yd[i], zd[i]]
    new_rows.append(new_row)
df_new = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns=cols)], axis=0) 
print(df_new)
print(df_new.info())
```

Output:

```
    P/N       Date  x    y    z
0  10a1 2022-07-01  0  1.1 -0.8
1  10a2 2022-07-03  1  1.2  0.0
2  10a3 2022-07-05  2  1.3  0.8  

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   P/N     3 non-null      object        
 1   Date    3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 2   x       3 non-null      int64         
 3   y       3 non-null      float64       
 4   z       3 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Rene, thanks for showing me how to explicitly add dtypes for multiple columns to the initial empty dataframe. Rows can then be added using either lists, series, dicts, etc., and the dtypes are preserved. I still think there is a bug in `concat`.